# Prevent re-renders while using useContext hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I have two distinct contexts in my application - Language and Currency. Each of these contexts are consumed by two distinct functional components through the useContext hook. When one of the context values change I want React to only invoke the functional component that consumes that context and not the other. However I find that both functional components get invoked when either context values change. How can I prevent this? Even if React doesn't re-render unchanged DOM after reconciliation I would like to prevent actually calling of the functional component itself.In other words how can I memoize each component (or something similar) while still maintaining my code organization (See below)?

LanguageContext.js

```
import React from 'react';
const LanguageContext = React.createContext({ lang: 'english', changeLang: (lang) => { } });

export { LanguageContext };
```

CurrencyContext.js

```
import React from 'react';

const CurrencyContext = React.createContext({ cur: '$', changeCur: (cur) => { } });

export { CurrencyContext };
```

ContextRoot.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { LanguageContext } from '../context/LanguageContext';
import { CurrencyContext } from '../context/CurrencyContext';

const ContextRoot = (props) => {
    const [lang, setLang] = useState('english');
    const [cur, setCur] = useState('$');

    const changeLang = (lang) => {
        setLang(lang);
    }

    const changeCur = (cur) => {
        setCur(cur);
    }

    const langCtx = {
        lang,
        changeLang
    };

    const curCtx = {
        cur,
        changeCur
    };

    return (
        <LanguageContext.Provider value={langCtx}>
            <CurrencyContext.Provider value={curCtx}>
                {props.children}
            </CurrencyContext.Provider>
        </LanguageContext.Provider>
    );
}

export { ContextRoot };
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Header } from './Header';
import { Welcome } from './Welcome';
import { Currency } from './Currency';
import { ContextRoot } from './ContextRoot';

const App = (props) => {
    return (
        <ContextRoot>
            <div>
                <Header />
                <Welcome />
                <Currency />
            </div>
        </ContextRoot>
    );
}

export { App };
```

Header.js

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { LanguageContext } from '../context/LanguageContext';
import { CurrencyContext } from '../context/CurrencyContext';

const Header = (props) => {
    const { changeLang } = useContext(LanguageContext);
    const { changeCur } = useContext(CurrencyContext);

    const handleLangClick = (lang) => {
        changeLang(lang);
    };

    const handleCurClick = (cur) => {
        changeCur(cur);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Select your language: <button onClick={e => handleLangClick('english')}>English </button> <button onClick={e => handleLangClick('spanish')}>Spanish</button></h2>
            <h2>Select your Currency: <button onClick={e => handleCurClick('$')}>Dollars </button> <button onClick={e => handleCurClick('€')}>Euros</button></h2>
        </div>
    );
};

export { Header };
```

Welcome.js

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { LanguageContext } from '../context/LanguageContext';

const Welcome = (props) => {
    console.log('welcome..');
    const { lang } = useContext(LanguageContext);
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{lang === 'english' ? 'Welcome' : 'Bienvenidos'}</h1>
        </div>

    );

};

export { Welcome };
```

Currency.js

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { CurrencyContext } from '../context/CurrencyContext';

const Currency = () => {
    console.log('currency..');
    const { cur } = useContext(CurrencyContext);
    return (
        <h2>Your chosen currency: {cur}</h2>
    )
}

export { Currency };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need is `useMemo`. It's pretty easy to implement, take a look in docs to apply your needs. Hope help you :)

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo

Comment: Yes, looks like useMemo would make things more efficient though not in this particular case because there are no complex computations in render.